# Geocortex workflow 5 calculate service area

Tags: geocortex, workflow

How can I use calculate service area activity in Geocortex workflow 5?

I have tried all the possible ways using ArcGIS NA Server service layer. When I am running the workflow error is displayed: `invalid workflow inputs`. I am unable to understand what is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can post the issue with perhaps some code sample on the Geocortex site. https://communities.geocortex.com/s/   Other Geocortex WF5 developers will help you.

Also it is always better to not use acronyms for search&find functionality
(I assume your NA means "network Analyst" or "Network Analysis"?)

I have no experience invoking ArcGIS NA Server service layer but my guess would be:

With Geocortex WF5 you can run a "Run geoprocessing" activity and perhaps invoke a REST end point of your ArcGIS server network Analyst.
A "run web Request" activity could be useful too https://docs.geocortex.com/workflow/latest/help/Default.htm#wf5/help/activities/web-request.htm